# TransportControls for two MediaPlayerElement

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp

I just have 2 MediaPlayerElement and I want them to connect to MediaTransportControls Xaml controll. How can I do this ? I tried to do {Binding ElementName=myTransportControls} but it doesn't work

Comment: Could you please post some complete codes to show what you are trying?

Comment: I have nothing to show :) because it's simple mediaelement. I want control two mediaelement by one MediaTransportControls. Is it possible ?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible. You can try [System Media Transport Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/integrate-with-systemmediatransportcontrols) instead, if it fits your requirement.

Comment: ok, as I thought. Thank you